# Does strict mode in one function have an effect on a function it calls?

Tags: javascript, strict

For example, I have code like this:

```
function test() {
  // some code
}

function main() {
  "use strict";
  test();
}
```

As you can see - in function `main` I have enabled strict mode.

**Question:** does this enable strict mode in function `test` or I need to define strict mode for each function separately?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30117694/1903116) as well, it has few examples explaining it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Strict mode is *scoped*. So only the code within your `main` is in strict mode.

Note that while strict mode is scoped, *some* effects of it *can* be seen outside of strict mode code. That isn't the case with your code, but I thought I should mention it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871050/inconsistent-scope-of-use-strict-on-different-web-browsers-concerning-argumen) and its answers go into that in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

No, since javascript has function level scope, right now strict is scoped to the function main only. If you want it to be scoped to other functions, you can either specify *"use strict";* globally or specify it for required functions individually.

Note: specifying it gloablly will affect all the functions whatsoever.